# Django: ошибка во время миграции

Tags: python, django, миграция

Миграцию ни одну не сделал и не могу запустить сервер, сделать `makemigrations`, `migrate` вылетает эта ошибка:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА: отношение "authorization_university" не существует
>   LINE 1: ...le", "authorization_university"."decryption" FROM "authoriza...
>                                                                ^

Код ORM:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class University(models.Model):
    university_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    decryption = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)

class Regkey(models.Model):
    key = models.IntegerField()

class Profile_student(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Обнаружил что когда удаляю функцию в `forms.py`, спокойно все делается и запускается сервера и миграция:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Regkey, University, Group as groupdb

def func_university():                    #ВОТ ЭТУ ФУНКЦИЮ
    all_university = University.objects.all()
    university_list = ()
    university_array = []
    for university_for in all_university:
        university_list = (university_for.university_id, university_for.title)
        university_array.append(university_list)
    return university_array


class SignUpFormStudent(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Имя')
    second_name = forms.CharField(label='Фамилия')
    middle_name = forms.CharField()
    group = forms.CharField(label='Группа')
    university = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=func_university())
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean(self):
        reg_data = super(SignUpFormStudent, self).clean()
        university = reg_data.get("university")
        group = reg_data.get("group")
        email = reg_data.get("email")
        if not groupdb.objects.filter(group = group, university = university):
            msg = 'Такой группы нет'
            self._errors['group'] = self.error_class([msg])
            del reg_data['group']
        if User.objects.filter(email = email):
            msg = 'Эта электронная почта занята'
            self._errors['email'] = self.error_class([msg])
            del reg_data['email']
        return reg_data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'group', 'password1', 'password2')


class SignUpFormDean(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Имя')
    second_name = forms.CharField(label='Фамилия')
    middle_name = forms.CharField()
    university = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=func_university())
    regkey = forms.CharField(label='Номер ключа', max_length = 16)

    def clean(self):
        data = super(SignUpFormDean, self).clean()
        regkey_input = data.get("regkey")
        if not regkey.objects.get(key = regkey_input):
            msg = 'Неверный ключ или он уже был использован'
            self._errors['regkey'] = self.error_class([msg])
            del data['regkey']
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','second_name', 'email', 'regkey', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Comment: Это точно весь код? Есть сомнения, т.к `authorization_university` нигде нет. И попробуйте убрать отношения между сущностями, сделать первую миграцию, потом добавить отношения и сделать миграцию уже по существующей схеме.

Comment: Весь. Я убрал везде university. И смог сделать миграцию. Потом добавил University с одним столбцом. Сделал еще одну миграцию, все сработало. Решил добавить еще один столбец к university и опять вышла ошибка но теперь то что нет столбца. Использую Django 3, это может повлиять?

Comment: Обнаружил что когда удаляю функцию в Forms, спокойно все делается и запускается сервера и миграция. Вопрос обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда происходит миграция в коде не должно быть работы с моделями, у Вас вызывается `University.objects.all()`. Чтобы этого избежать создайте функцию для проверки статуса миграции:

```py
import sys

def is_migration():
    # Проверка аргументов командной строки на наличие миграции
    return 'makemigrations' in sys.argv or 'migrate' in sys.argv
```

Удобно эту функцию положить в файлик вроде `utils.py`. Затем используйте её чтобы предотвратить обращения к БД при миграции. Например, так:

```
def func_university():
    university_array = []
    # Ничего не делать во время миграции
    if is_migration():
        return university_array

    all_university = University.objects.all()
    for university_for in all_university:
        university_list = (university_for.university_id, university_for.title)
        university_array.append(university_list)
    return university_array
```

<sub>PS: переменную `university_list` перед циклом объявлять не обязательно.</sub>

Comment: Костыль так-то.

Comment: @andreymal Такое же решение видел на enSO и много где ещё `(:` Вы знаете вариант лучше?